# Homology group of a triangulation(simplicial complex) space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, triangulation, simplicial-complex

Let $X$ be a connected oriented triangulation(polyhedron) space, i.e., homeomorphic to a geometric realization of an oriented simplicial complex $S$ with dimension $n$, and the boundary $\partial S$ of $S$ is 0, is the homology group $H_n(X,Z)$ isomorphic to $Z$?

Comment: What is your definition of $\partial S$ for an arbitrary simplicial complex?

Comment: just the face of simplexes in the usual sense, considered the induced orientation, they will cancel out

Comment: Take the wedge of two spheres.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no: if $X$ is the wedge of two $n$-spheres, then $H_n(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.